# Calculate Average of Column Data with Headers

Tags: awk

I have data for example that looks like this:

```
Flats 2b 
01/1991, 3.45
01/1992, 4.56
01/1993, 4.21
01/1994, 5.21
01/1995, 7.09
01/2013, 6.80
Eagle 2
01/1991, 4.22
01/1992, 6.32
01/1993, 5.21
01/1994, 8.09
01/1995, 7.92
01/2013, 6.33
```

I'm trying to calculate an average of column 2 so that my desired output looks like this preferably:

```
Flats 2b
Avg = 4.67
Eagle 2
Avg = 5.26
```

or even simpler that looks like this without the header:
    Avg = 4.67
    Avg = 5.26

and so on...since the input file is full of many headers with data like that shown above.

I have tried to do pattern matching options and using NR with something like this without success as an awk one-liner:

```
awk '/01/1991,/01/1993 {sum+=$2; cnt+=1} {print "Avg =" sum/cnt}' myfile.txt
```

I get averages but not my desired average for JUST the years 1991, 1992 and 1993 separately for each met tower.
Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to consider only the years 1991-1993

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# new header, print average if exists, reset values
/[a-zA-Z]/ {
    if (cnt > 0) {
        print header;
        printf("Avg = %.2f\n", sum/cnt);
    }
    header=$0; sum=0; cnt=0;
}

# calculate average
/^01\/199[123]/ { sum+=$2; cnt++; }

# print last average
END {
    if (cnt > 0) {
        print header;
        printf("Avg = %.2f\n", sum/cnt);
    }
}
```

This looks for awk script looks for a header, prints an average, if there is one and then  resets all variables for the next average calculation. If it finds a data row it calculates the sum needed for the average later. If last line is read it prints the final average.

The script considers only the years 1991 until 1993 inclusive. If you want to include more years, you can either duplicate the calculation line or add multiple years with the or operator `||`

```
# calculate average
/^01\/199[0-9]/ || /^01\/200[0-9]/ { sum+=$2; cnt++; }
```

This takes all the 1990s and 2000s into account.

If you don't want to print the headers, remove the appropriate lines `print header`.

You call this awk script as

```
awk -f script.awk myfile.txt
```

Comment: thanks, but I have added some edits to help I think with a solution.

Comment: Hello and thanks.  How do i execute this? ./yourscript myfile...? I'm getting an error line 5 /[a-zA-Z]/: No such file or directory and syntax error on line 6 near unexpected token `{' and also on line 6 if (cnt > 0) {'

Comment: thanks - it works now but my input file actually is in the format mm/yyyy from Jan (01) 1991 through Jan (01) of 2013.  I need to average all the years (1991-2012) EXCEPT the last - 01/2013.  Thank you very much.

Comment: THANKS - I figured out a hack to get the average of 1991-2012.  thanks again,